# ANTLR charVocabulary error

Tags: parsing, unicode, antlr

I'm trying to have a UNICODE grammar in ANTLR, but this always causes error (snippet of grammar):

```
grammar Expression;

options {
  charVocabulary='\u000'..'\uFFFE';
}

parse
  :  exp EOF
;

exp
  : 'a'
 ;
```

It always ends up at: `'\uFFFE' not expected ';'`. How to write correct UNICODE grammars - what's the correct `charVocabulary` definition?

I'm using ANTLR 3.2, but it causes same error in new versions also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charVocabulary` is an ANTLR v2 option, not available in ANTLR v3 grammars. All lexers generated from ANTLR v3 grammars accept characters in the range `\u0000..\uFFFF` (be sure to use the proper encoding while creating an [ANTLRInputStream](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_a_n_t_l_r_input_stream.html)!).

When using ANTLRWorks, you can see this by defining a rule, `Any`, that matches any character:

```
Any : . ;
```

and you will see the following diagram being displayed in the lower part of ANTLRWorks:

[image]